# Most popular, trusted rpm dnf repos for CentOS Stream 8 ans RedHat 8 Enterprise Linux

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, repository, dnf

Could you please point me to several rpm repositories that hold binary compatible packages for CentOS Stream 8 and / or RHEL 8 so I can use dnf to find newer versions of standard packages or software that is not available from official IBM Red Hat repositories?

I mean for example

- kernel, modules and header packages - I am using v5.11 with another distribution, while CentOS Stream is still with v4
- Video for Linux Utils - openSuse has v4l-utils v1.20 I am using 1.18 with another distro, and CentOS 8 is still with v1.14 which makes some software work incorrectly
- Cheese - Fedora has now v3.38, I am using 3.34 on another machine, while CentOS is now with ancient 3.28 not working properly

Perhaps cheese is not crucial now, but some other tools are and I bet there software developers shall have their own repos with each app respectively to install latest stable matching reqs version just like most vendors have ppa in Debian ecosystem.

Comment: Do you mean like `testing` or third party repos? Can you mention a specific package that you need a more up to date version of?

Comment: Does it answer enough?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think your best bet would be to enable some of [these repos](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) or [RPM fusion](https://rpmfusion.org/), as these may take care of some of them. It seems like the 'Additional resources' page also can be helpful if you want a newer (experimental) kernel. You could try to enable the repos mentioned from the site I linked and try to search for, for example, `cheese` and see if it is newer; if not, you can disable it again, if you wish to do so. I use fedora, so I don't know CentOS too well but they are similar in some things

Comment: On the https://rpmfusion.org/RPM%20Fusion I went for EL 8 updates x86_64 arch and the list of available packages is severely limited both for free and non-free software. As for me it seems that software developers would do not package their software for CentOS / RHEL. Looks like that rpm ecosystem is lacking something to attract independent developers and they target other platforms. What a shame. Or perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: There has been a lot of drama around RH and CentOS. Tbh, I haven't followed it too much, but ppl say that RH basically killed CentOS... and that its true successor seems to be Rocky Linux. I don't know if you are using CentOS through your organization but, if it's for personal use, you could try to spin up Rocky in a VM to see if you have more luck there. I say this because I don't use COS and maybe developers do it on purpose not to create packages for it (pointless to make/update packages for a dead project). Sorry I couldn't be of more help :/

Comment: There are two equivalent clones of RHEL: Alma and Rocky Linux. They are binary compatible, i.e. whatever works with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 or CentOS Stream 8 would work with Alma and Rocky and vice versa. In terms of rpm there is no difference. If you can suggest some Rocky rpm repos that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

As a frame challenge, CentOS/RHEL is probably not the distribution for you if you are looking for the latest and greatest packages. The ideology behind package versioning in CentOS/RHEL is to be stable before all else - this often means that packages are held at a certain feature level and only bugfixes are backported from the current version.

Running newer packages than the developers intended may seem harmless, and is the majority of the time, but there is always the small chance that something would go wrong. In the Debian world this is called creating a FrankenDebian and it risks breaking your system if an external repository offers versions of core libraries that are newer, and thus will overwrite the installed and known-good ones. I frequently see this when users install programs from external repositories that overwrite `glibc`, and at that point we typically just reinstall the entire system as it's not worth it to disentangle.

I will link the Don't Break Debian page below, as it generally applies to CentOS/RHEL and other "stable" Linux distributions. It is in general a good mentality to keep if you wish to retain your sanity working in Linux.

https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Comment: I fully understand that. On the other hand this my test / learning system. I was RedHat fan before it went commercial and as the years passed the landscape change considerably. The system is as much usable as the software it provides. That's why Snaps and Flathub appeared where the app is packaged with all the libs it requires in a "virtual-like" env. I was pretty much astonished that rpm ecosystem is not only lacking backporting but also newer builds or more precisely rebuilding old sw for new versions. Let's treat this question as a sort of "how to make CentOS usable" place.

Answer (score 0):

I found actually 2 interesting repos:

```
$ sudo dnf install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
```

is commercial and requires subscription.

This one:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/8/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-5.el8.noarch.rpm
```

also contains some software and updates.

Some needed software I found in Snap:

```
$ sudo dnf install snapd
...
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
...
$ sudo snap install snap-store
...
```

Note: it takes several minutes for systemctl to finish and you're likely to get some SELinux warnings plus a message:

```
error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged
```

In my case after waiting half an hour, reboot and retrying snap-store install went on and I was able to install the packages I needed.

Another software source is Flatpak / Flathub. I did not try it though as it contained older versions of the software.